# Android service does not stop with stopself() and onDestroy Implementation

Tags: android, android-service

I have BroadcasReceiver[BR] and Service Module[SM] that is launched from BR with intent. I am planning to perform a functionality that needs to be run only once and stop the service completely. I have tried following flow and does not work the way it's expected. I believe onDestroy is never called even though stopSelf() is triggered. am I missing something? Someone has also suggested onDestroy is not guaranteed. What would be other way to clean up then?

I have gone through all available posts here but did not find anything helpful.

**NOTE** :

- onDestroy is never called [I'm assuming this will be triggered with stopSelf()].
- service is still running in foreground [which should've been taken care with stopForeground(true)]
- I am reviewing it by checking if it's listed in `ps | grep`. it always shows up. I am assuming if service stops itself, it should not appear in running processes.
- Also, I have verified that condition is met in if statement which should trigger stop service.

```
public class target extends service {
   @override
   onStartCommand {
      // logs the call
      if(condition true) {
         // validates it's already run before so no need to continue
         stopForeground(true);
         stopSelf();
         return START_NOT_STICKY;
      }
      .
      .
      .   
      return START_NOT_STICKY;
   }

   action() {
      // logs the call
      .
      .
      .
      if(condition true) {
         // validates it's purpose and stops self
         stopForeground(true);
         stopSelf();
         return;
      }
   }

   @override
   onDestroy {
      // logs the call
      .   
      .
   }
}
```

and in Receiver :

```
public class targetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @override
   onReceive() {
      // logs the call
      if (condition true) {
         // Service has already performed it's job so no need to start it again
         return;
      }
      // else continue
      .
      .
      .
   }
}
```

Comment: From what you're showing we can't really help you, could you c/c your actual SM and BR ? Also the fuction is `stopSelf()` with capital S.

Comment: @Biscuit, The Given code is target -> SM and targetReceiver -> BR. Consider, it's a correct format and compiles successfully. I'll update it for readability.

Comment: It's not about readability, we need the exact code you're using to help you debug it.
From what you share with us, your service should stop correctly, unfortunately it's not the case with your real code, so show it to us.
Besides your Broadcaster should be the one knowing if your Service has been launched before in order not to call it, instead of creating it then destroying it